# A salesforce custom button throws out of memory javascript error

Tags: javascript, button, salesforce, out-of-memory

I have created a custom button on Contact object. The button is displayed in a list view. It aims at updating two fields in the selected Contact records in the list view.

The code is the following:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT ("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")} 
var records ={!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Contact)}; 
var newRecords = []; 
var today = new Date(); 

if (records[0] == null) { 
  alert("Sélectionnez au moins un Contact") 
} 
else { 

  for (var n=0; n<records.length; n++) { 
   var c = new sforce.SObject("Contact"); 
   c.id = records[n]; 
   c.E_mail_proposition_intervention__c = true; 
   c.Date_envoi_e_mail_proposition_interventi__c = today; 
   newRecords.push(c); 
  } 

result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload(); 
alert("E-mails envoyés"); 
}`
```

In Firefox: when selecting records in the list view and clicking on the button, it does the job but throws an error: "out of memory"

In IE or Chrome: no error.

Do I need to change something in the javascript code?

Thank you,
Anne

Comment: In IE and chrome, is it working as expected?

Comment: You are trying to show an alert after reloading the page (and hence terminating the script). Try getting rid of those last two lines and see if you still get the error.